# Sign in multiple player at the same time or store login-cookie for Google play games services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I wonder if it is possible to sign in multiple player at the same time or store the login-info somehow for Google play games services. I developed a scorepad app and would love to sync games from different devices with the PlayGames-Accounts of the players. They are all present and play with one device. So it would be useful if different players can stay logged in on this device. Is this possible? Actually they dont have to be logged in at the same time, but it would be nice if they would only have to enter their login-data once on each device.
What do you think?
Thank you for your thoughts
Frank J.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to sign in and out of an account associated with Google Play Games on an Android device. The separate accounts will have private leaderboard scores, achievements, cloud saves, and so on.

Comment: But is it possible (and if so:how) to store the account info of different logins?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to store the account info for all of the accounts on a device in the same place?

Comment: Yes one device multiple players play the same game (account info saved in a database) and the data should be updated after the game is finished. So maybe login player1, save data, logout, login player2, save data, logout... but without entering the login data each time/each game, but just once in the beginning.